# Cosa vuol dire "scamuso"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Lo conosceva da tempo perché Cichitto ronzava attorno al negozio, veniva a mendicare, con quella voce fioca che sembrava il miagolio di un gatto sperso, e Agnello gli regalava sempre qualche banana marcia. Cichitto, che era gracile, rognoso e **scamuso** come un randagio, si sedeva per terra, fuori dalla bottega, e s’ingozzava subito, senza mettere niente da parte.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato di "scamuso"? Non ho trovato questo termine su nessun dizionario. Sospetto che si tratti di un termine regionale, possibilmente imparentato con il napoletano.

Comment: Possibilmente collegato con [*camuso*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/camuso/)?

Answer (score 1):

In questo blog si trova l'articolo *[Un'antica parola napoletana: scamuso](http://lellobrak.blogspot.com/2008/12/unantica-parola-napoletana-scamuso.html)* si può leggere:

> Antico, icastico aggettivo napoletano presente in tutti i dizionarii
>   d’antan dal D’Ambra al P.P.Volpe all’Andreoli e negli scritti di
>   autori dal ‘600 alla fine dell’ ‘800 e poi non piú riscontrato negli
>   autori piú moderni, sebbene ancóra vivo nel parlato soprattutto del
>   popolo della città bassa, aggettivo riferito con piccole differenze
>   sia a soggetti animati che inanimati; 
> **Riferito a soggetti animati e
>   piú precisamente a persone significa in italiano: **rozzo, grossolano,
>   rustico, grezzo e per ampiamento semantico si disse di persona magra ed
>   allampanata;**  riferito a cose inanimate(stoffe e/o oggetti) vale
>   nell’italiano: ruvido,squamoso,irto

Più avanti nel testo il termine viene spiegato con più precisione:

> E veniamo finalmente all’aggetivo napoletano **scamuso** del cui
>   significato primo (malandato etc.) ò già détto e qui rammento che è
>   aggettivo da numerosi sinonimi (sebbene alcuni derivati da un
>   ampliamenti semantici quali acciaccuso, acciuppecuto, ammaturo,
>   dellicato, iétteco malepatuto; mi occuperò in coda di tali sinonimi;
>   affrontiamo ora l’etimologia di scamuso ed escludiamo súbito la facile
>   ma fallace tentazione di un collegamento alla voce scamunéa/éja/era
>   s.f. che con derivazione dal lat. *scammonia/scammonea che furono dal
>   greco skammonía indicò in primis un'erba dal cui estratto si ricavava
>   un purgante ed indicò poi (forse per un traslato espressivo) gente
>   vile, bordaglia, unione di monelli e, piú genericamente, plebaglia, ma
>   ognuno vede che semanticamente è difficile trovare il collegamento tra
>   un’erba purgativa ed un vocabolo che vale malandato, messo male mal
>   ridotto, malsano; ugualmente non mi sento di poter accettare l’idea di
>   chi propone per scamuso un collegamento etimologico con squamoso (cfr.
>   antea); è vero che il significato di squamoso nell’accezione di
>   ruvido, irto può – all’incirca – valere il napoletano scamuso come è
>   pure vero che il nesso latino qua dà spesso il napoletano ca (cfr. ad
>   es. exquassare→scassare) pur tuttavia non mi sento di accogliere la
>   proposta che presupporrebbe un transito di accostamento ad un vocabolo
>   della lingua italiana, accostamenti che ò sempre bandito e non per un
>   colpevole provincialismo, ma in nome di un'originaria derivazione di
>   tutte le voci partenopee dagli antichi idiomi (latino, greco ed
>   altro); d’altro canto nemmeno mi convice l’etimologia proposta
>   dall’amico prof. Carlo Iandolo che lègge in scamuso una s intensiva
>   che precede l’avverbio greco kamái = a terra ottenendo da
>   skamái→scamuso; questa proposta, semanticamente mi appare troppo
>   debole e morfomogicamente, sforzata con quell’unione di greco skamái
>   con un suff. latino osus/oso&→uso.
>   
> A questo punto non rimane che prender per buona l’antica idea che vede in scamuso una derivazione metaplasmatica dello spagnolo (e)scamocho che accanto al significato di avanzo e resto à pure quelli di persona magra, allampanata; d’altro canto nello spagnolo è anche vivo il verbo escamochar (guastare, sciupare) che à fornito altresí il verbo napoletano scamuscià/are nei significati di afflosciare, diventar floscio e/o senza forze.

Anche nel libro *[Eduardo. Dizionario dei personaggi](https://books.google.it/books?id=vTQgBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT27&lpg=PT27&dq=scamuso%20significato&source=bl&ots=sFQ4dD-aUf&sig=ACfU3U0xBReu26x37c4hvEhxBS12xG6IOw&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZwLDdqp3jAhVRUlAKHffCDKkQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=scamuso%20significato&f=false)* di Nicola De Blasi, Bianchi Patricia compare la seguente definizione:

> In *Quei figuri di trent'anni fa* compare l'assassino **Scamuso**
>   (**'rozzo, grossolano'**) e il ladro Scuppettella (diminutivo di
>   "scuppetta", 'archibugio, schioppo').

In questo documento intitolato 
*[Chi è stregato dallo Strega? Rilievi di stile sugli ultimi romanzi vincitori (2002-2009)](http://lellobrak.blogspot.com/2008/12/unantica-parola-napoletana-scamuso.html)* ho trovato:

> 101); zezzilli capezzoli” (p. 107); lorcia “sudiciume” (p. 109);
>   **scamuso “molto magro”** (p. 113); alleccamussi “ceffoni” (p. 113, 176);
>   ***cozzeca “crosta di una ferita”***

Answer (score 1):

A pagina 176 dello studio [“Ispanismi nel dialetto napoletano”](http://www.ilc.it/Giovanna%2520Riccio%2520-%2520Ispanismi%2520nel%2520napoletano.pdf) di Giovanna Riccio, a cura di Marcello Marinucci, pubblicato nel 2005 presso l’Università di Trieste, si possono leggere le definizioni di "scamuso" riportate da parecchi dizionari:

> ***scamuso/-osa*** agg. 'ruvido, rozzo' (D'Ambra 1873); 'squamoso' (Andreoli 
>   1887); fig. 'di uomo ruvido, scontroso' (ib.); 'modesto, di scarto, malandato' 
>   (Altamura 1968; D'Ascoli 1972).
>
> > > > Secondo D'Ascoli (1972) la v. è da ricondurre allo sp. 
> > > >         *escamocho* (intorno al 1300, trad. di Abenbassal, DCECH s.v. 
> > > >         *campo*) nel suo sign. di 'persona magra e allampanata'.
> > > >         Altamura (1968) indica invece come base il sost. *scamunera*
> > > >         (it. *scamonèa* fig. 'persona malsana o uggiosa' DEI V 3368).
> > > >         La v. è da ricondurre alla base  **squamare*, cfr. *scamusu*
> > > >         'cisposo' (Faré 8200).

Sono state utilizzate le seguenti abbreviazioni:

> agg. = aggettivo 
>   fig. = figurato
>   ib. = ibidem
>   v. = voce 
>   sp. = spagnolo 
>   s.v. = sub voce / si veda 
>   sign. = significato 
>   sost. = sostantivo (ato) 
>   it. = italiano 
>   cfr. = confronta

Fonti:

> - ALTAMURA A., *Dizionario dialettale napoletano*, 
>     Fiorentino, Napoli 1968.
> - ANDREOLI R., *Vocabolario napoletano-italiano*, 
>     Paravia, Torino 1887.
> - D'AMBRA R., *Vocabolario napolitano-toscano domestico di arti e mestieri*, Chiurazzi, Napoli 1873.
> - D'ASCOLI F., *Lingua spagnuola e dialetto napoletano*, 
>     Libreria Scientifica, Napoli 1972.
> - DCECH = COROMINAS J. PASCUAL J. A., *Diccionario crítico etimológico castellano e hispánico*, Gredos, Madrid, vol. I (ACA) 1987; vol. II (CEF) 1984; vol. III (GMA)
>     1984; vol. IV (MERE) 1985; vol. V (RIX) 1986; vol. VI (YZ) 1991.
> - DEI = BATTISTI C. ALESSIO G., *Dizionario etimologico italiano*, 5 voll., Barbera Firenze 1950-1957.
> - FARÉ A. P., *Postille italiane al REW*, Istituto di Scienze e Lettere, Milano 1972.